# Errors from a .NET 3.5 project show up as .NET 2.x

Tags: .net, asp.net, clr, error-logging

While my ASP.NET project uses **version 3.5 of the framework**, the event log registers errors as coming from **version 2.X of the framework** such as this:

```
Event Type:         Error
Event Source:       ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category:     None
Event ID:           1334
Date:               2009-05-19
Time:               17:04:29
User:               N/A
Computer:           XXXXXXXXXX

Description:
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/234989001/Root
Process ID: 8912
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746.
```

Comment: I've actually wondered this too, thanks for the question.

Comment: It was a question from a co-worker that I didn't see posted anywhere on here so I thought I'd add it.  Received a good answer before I could answer it myself :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are all based on the 2.0 CLR. The version you see is the CLR version, not the Framework version, so everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has a different version number to the underlying .Net framework.

ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0 can runs with .Net 3.5 - your error message is reporting the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

For more information, I found this post by Scott Hanselman informative:

[How to set an IIS Application or AppPool to use ASP.NET 3.5 rather than 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx)